# Install packages with yum to alt python location

Tags: python, python-2.7, rhel, rhel6

I am currently running RHEL 6.6. This has `python 2.6.6` pre-installed and is the default. I installed `python 2.7` using the `altinstall` method. The default python is still `2.6.6`. I'm trying to install the `python-devel` packages using `yum` which only runs with root. However when I run `yum install python-devel` as root it installs the packages to `python 2.6.6`.

Is there a way to get yum to install packages using the alt python install?

Comment: `python-devel` is just the Python headers; you already have those if you downloaded from python.org.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use the Python 2.7 version that is available as part of "Software Collections".  This is installed along side the original 2.6 and doesn't try to replace it (and is included in nearly all RHEL subscriptions.) See info here:

Introduction: http://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/overview/

List of available components including Python 2.7:  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html/2.0_Release_Notes/chap-RHSCL.html#sect-RHSCL-Features

It's still a yum install, but with an extra command or two.  You can start with this Get Started guide for Python 3.4 (http://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/get-started-rhel6-python/) but swap out the Python versions in steps 2 and 3.